# What's the difference between a power plan and a power mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, battery

In Windows 10 when I click the battery icon in the system tray a box appears asking me if I want to switch to better battery, better performance or best performance.

Also there's an option called Power Options that is opened by right clicking the battery icon or by going to control panel. In Power Options there are options to change the power plan.

[image: power options and power mode in windows 10]

Obviously a power **plan** and a power **mode** are two completely different things, as changing the power mode **doesn't** change the power plan.

So what is a power mode and where is its settings defined? What settings does changing the power mode *actually* change if the modes don't appear in Power Options. And what's the difference between a power plan and a power mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is a power mode and where is its settings defined?

According to [Customize the Windows performance power slider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-power-slider),

> The Windows performance power slider enables end customers to quickly and intelligently trade performance of their system for longer battery life. As a customer switches between the four slider modes to trade performance for battery life (or vice versa), Windows power settings are engaged behind the scenes.

Its settings are exactly where you clicked and shown on th eimage posted with the question:

> Customers can access the slider on their Windows device by clicking or tapping the battery icon in the task bar. The slider appears in the battery flyout.

There are 4 power/slider modes:

- Battery Saver
- Better battery
- Better performance
- Best performance

> what's the difference between a power plan and a power mode?

A power plan as stated on [What are power plans and how to switch between them in Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/understanding-power-plans-how-switch-between-them) is:

> a collection of hardware and system settings that manages how your PC, laptop, or tablet uses power. The power plans available depend on the kind of PC that you have and whether its manufacturer did or did not customize the default power plans available in Windows. Some power plans are designed to deliver high performance while compromising battery life while others are made so that you get as much battery life as possible while compromising the performance.

The difference (if it can be difference) is the fact:

> That power slider adds new power saving algorithms and technologies, on top of the active power plan, which has to be the Balanced one. The power slider does not change the active power plan!

Comment: Why don't I have the `better battery life` option on my performance slider?

Comment: @desbest IT's Battery Saver. I edited the post.

Comment: Why don't I have the `battery saver` option in my performance slider?

Comment: Slide it to the extreme left.