# Win 11: What performance characteristics does the "power mode" setting change

Tags: windows-11, battery, power

(1) In Windows 11 there's a new settings item `System -> Power & Battery`, which under `Power mode` gives 3 choices: "Best Power efficiency", "Balanced", and "Best Performance".

(2) Moreover, in `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` there's still the `Change advanced power settings` dialogue, but this (at least on my system) only contains the `Balanced` item, which is checked to be active always, independently of what is chosen in (1).

(3) Moreover, when in (1) I choose "Best Performance", my OEM will inform me that I have activated a "Ultra Performance Mode".

[image: Power mode settings in Win 11]

This tells me that (1) is somehow set or influenced by my OEM's settings, but I have not found any documentation whatsoever about what system characteristics the three options ("Best Power efficiency" / "Balanced" / "Best Performance") change. The related  [Windows 11 help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/power-efficient-settings-in-windows-11-0d6a2b6b-2e87-4611-9980-ac9ea2175734) is laughable, and I haven't found anything online in forums etc. The closest I find on SU is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1597098/714576), but it's about a different setting in Win 10.

The Control Panel Settings (2) still let you choose stuff as processor power state, screen timeout, battery level actions and so on, but while I haven't tested this extensively, they don't seem to have any effect anymore and seem to be overridden completely by (1).

So, my Question: Which system parameters are influenced by the choice made in (1) ? Is there any (hidden) user settings that could be changed (other than the "Screen and Sleep" setting on the same Settings page) ?

Ultimately, I'd like to know how the behavior of my system will change when choosing one over the other power modes.

Comment: The problem you have is you have two pieces of software handling battery management, Lenovos Battery Management software and Windows itself.

Comment: @Ramhound I could uninstall Lenovo Vantage, the question remains the same. There's no clue whatsoever as to what's actually being modified: processor states? P/E cores priority management? disk use? background processes?  what else?